Нужна ли точка в данном случае?
Скажите, пожалуйста, как оформлять пунктуацию в случае, если предложение заканчивается вопросительной/восклицательной прямой речью?
Например:
Периодически он оборачивался и громко кричал: "Остановитесь!" или "Не ходите за мной!"(.)
Нужна ли в конце предложения в данном случае точка?

Точка не нужна.

В конце фразы после закрывающих цитату кавычек:
<...>
в) не ставят никаких знаков, если перед закрывающими кавычками стоит многоточие, вопросительный или восклицательный знак, а заключенная в кавычки цитата является самостоятельным предложением (таковы, как правило, все цитаты после двоеточия, отделяющего их от предшествующих им слов цитирующего):
Глава заканчивается словами: «Прощай, философия, прощай, молодость, прощай, Германия!»

Как оформлять цитаты? (Грамота.ру)
Примеры из справочника Розенталя:

Наконец я ей сказал: «Хочешь, пойдём прогуляться на вал?»
Лёжа на тюке и плача, он дёргал руками и ногами и шептал: «Мама! Мама!»
...А он: «Пошёл прочь, пьяная рожа!»
Не говорить же: Эй, собака!» или «Эй, кошка!


Александр, мне кажется здесь надо дать ссылку на  § 51.   Не говорить же: «Эй, собака!» или «Эй, кошка!» — две реплики, разделенные неповторяющимся союзом или;  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=159

@Sharon А какая разница – две или одна реплика? Речь же не об этом. Но я добавлю это предложение. Спасибо! // Моя ссылка ведёт сразу на все параграфы о прямой речи.
